# Dependency issues breaking apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I believe I may have some dependencies installed in the wrong version for my system, because I keep getting errors whenever I try to use `apt-get`. For instance:

```
sudo apt-get install minicom
```

results in these errors:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.12) but 2.13-38+deb7u8 is to be installed
 libc6 : Depends: libc-bin (= 2.13-38+deb7u8) but 2.11.2-10 is to be installed
         Breaks: locales (< 2.13)
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.13-38+deb7u8) but 2.11.2-10 is to be installed
             Breaks: gcc-4.4 (< 4.4.6-4) but 4.4.5-8 is to be installed
 locales : Depends: glibc-2.11-1
 ntp : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I try to fix it with `sudo apt-get -f install`. But I get almost identical errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.12) but 2.13-38+deb7u8 is installed
 libc6 : Depends: libc-bin (= 2.13-38+deb7u8) but 2.11.2-10 is installed
         Breaks: locales (< 2.13)
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.13-38+deb7u8) but 2.11.2-10 is installed
             Breaks: gcc-4.4 (< 4.4.6-4) but 4.4.5-8 is installed
 locales : Depends: glibc-2.11-1
 ntp : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Except this time, I get the two extra errors down at the bottom. I'm really at a loss here for how to solve this problem.

**Here is what I've tried so far:**

Firstly, links to related questions:

[Unable to install most major packages; Unmet dependencies and cannot be fixed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487405/unable-to-install-most-major-packages-unmet-dependencies-and-cannot-be-fixed)

[Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)

[Fix dependency when apt-get -f install fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398120/fix-dependency-when-apt-get-f-install-fails)

[E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel)

[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

[apt-get stopped working because of dependancy issue - libegl1-mesa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551783/apt-get-stopped-working-because-of-dependancy-issue-libegl1-mesa)

None of these questions or their answers helped me although I tried them all. The final link in that list seemed to most promising considering it has almost identical error messages, but it didn't solve my issue either.

**Here's a quick summary of what I've tried:**

- Removing files with `sudo apt-get remove [package]. This results in the exact same output as when I try to install anything.
- Looking at the `/var/log/apt/term.log` file for broken things to remove. This didn't really help because again, I can't remove anything.
- `sudo apt-get clean` then `sudo apt-get update` - clean returns nothing, and the update hits all my sources without problem. But it doesn't fix anything.
- `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` - returns similar issues to installing
- `apt-get install --reinstall [package]` on things that look broken - returns similar issues to installing
- `dpkg --remove [package]` - I've done this to a couple packages and it works, but as I'm not quite sure where the problem lies, this could just break things more.

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` (and any file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`)?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? See if you can install `aptitude` (`sudo apt-get install aptitude`) and use that instead of `apt-get`. It's more aggressive in fixing issues than `apt-get`, which means it can just resolve the problem and install `minicom`, but it can also remove some important packages. Be careful when you use it.

Comment: `+deb7u8` looks like Debian, not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems and I figured that in most cases the only thing you have to do is

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If that doesn't help, you should edit file `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and delete whole blocks of broken packages. Then repeat the first two commands and that's it.